# Change color of a single point by clicking on it - Chart.JS

Tags: chart.js

I'm building a scatter chart using Chart.JS(latest version), one of the behaviours I'm trying to implement is clicking on a single point and highlighting it by changing the background color of the selected point.

I've used the `getElementsAtEvent` method from the Chart.JS API in order to get the active element and change it's background. For a brief moment I can see it changing the color but it returns to its original color and all the other points now have the color I wanted to apply to the selected one... I tried various approaches to this, using the `updated` and `render` methods but with no desired result...

Here's the code inside the function that'll run `onClick`

```
function (evt, activeElements, chart) {
  const selectedPoint = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

  selectedPoint[0].element.options.backgroundColor = '#fa6400';

  chart.update();
}
```

Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dc3x70yg/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey @JPRB  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001579/how-to-change-the-color-of-chart-js-points-depending-on-the-label>. are you looking for this?

Comment: hi @NileshMishra, more or less, I want it to happen onClick on a single point...
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the option [`pointBackgroundColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point-styling) on the `dataset`. When the user clicks on a point, you recreate `pointBackgroundColor`, but now use an `array` that contains the desired color for each point.

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{ x: -10, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 10 }, { x: 10, y: 5 }, { x: 0.5, y: 5.5 }],
      pointBackgroundColor: '#ddd',
      pointRadius: 5,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (event, elements, chart) => {
      const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];     
      dataset.pointBackgroundColor = dataset.data.map((v, i) => i == elements[0]?.index ? '#fa6400': '#ddd');
      chart.update();
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```